A method to open jdk.compile from the lombok source
I referenced lombok.'s method of opening jdk.compile in jdk21,which opens jdk.complie at the initialization stage of the annotation processor
    private static void addOpensForLombok() {
        Class<?> cModule;
        try {
            cModule = Class.forName("java.lang.Module");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            return; //jdk8-; this is not needed.
        }

        Unsafe unsafe = getUnsafe();
        Object jdkCompilerModule = getJdkCompilerModule();
        Object ownModule = getOwnModule();
        String[] allPkgs = {
            "com.sun.tools.javac.code",
            "com.sun.tools.javac.comp",
            "com.sun.tools.javac.file",
            "com.sun.tools.javac.main",
            "com.sun.tools.javac.model",
            "com.sun.tools.javac.parser",
            "com.sun.tools.javac.processing",
            "com.sun.tools.javac.tree",
            "com.sun.tools.javac.util",
            "com.sun.tools.javac.jvm",
        };

        try {
            Method m = cModule.getDeclaredMethod("implAddOpens", String.class, cModule);
            long firstFieldOffset = getFirstFieldOffset(unsafe);
            unsafe.putBooleanVolatile(m, firstFieldOffset, true);
            for (String p : allPkgs) m.invoke(jdkCompilerModule, p, ownModule);
        } catch (Exception ignore) {}
    }

I use the maven clear install command to package the annotation processor into a jar file. Apply this annotation processor to other projects. Other projects compile with an error
 class org.example.async.log.client.annotation.AsyncLogProcessor (in unnamed module @0x201c3cda) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTrees (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.api to unnamed module @0x201c3cda


I debugged the compilation process through IDEA. I found that the getOwnModule method returns the unnamed module

    private static Object getOwnModule() {
        try {
            Method m = Permit.getMethod(Class.class, "getModule");
            return m.invoke(LombokProcessor.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

This method will get the unnamed module when other projects that depend on the annotation processor.
        try {
            Method m = cModule.getDeclaredMethod("implAddOpens", String.class, cModule);
            long firstFieldOffset = getFirstFieldOffset(unsafe);
            unsafe.putBooleanVolatile(m, firstFieldOffset, true);
            for (String p : allPkgs) m.invoke(jdkCompilerModule, p, ownModule);
        } catch (Exception ignore) {}

implAddOpens cannot open jdk.compile for unname module
    private void implAddExportsOrOpens(String pn,
                                       Module other,
                                       boolean open,
                                       boolean syncVM) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(other);
        Objects.requireNonNull(pn);

        // all packages are open in unnamed, open, and automatic modules
        if (!isNamed() || descriptor.isOpen() || descriptor.isAutomatic())
            return;

This means that the jdk.compile was not opened successfully.However, I have added module-info.java in my project
import javax.annotation.processing.Processor;
import org.example.async.log.client.annotation.AsyncLogProcessor;

module org.example.async.log.client{
    requires jdk.compiler;
    requires jdk.unsupported;

    exports org.example.async.log.client.annotation;
    provides Processor with AsyncLogProcessor;
}

The project of annotation processor is here
Test projects that depend on the annotation processor are here

Update: According to the answer of Naman, I conduct the following experiments.
remove it from <annotationProcessorPaths>
I removed the custom annotation processor in the <annotationProcessorPaths>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.13.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>21</source>
                    <target>21</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-proc:full</arg>
                        <arg>-Xlint:all</arg>
                        <arg>-verbose</arg>
                        <arg>-XprintRounds</arg>
                        <arg>-XprintProcessorInfo</arg>
                        <arg>-Xmaxerrs</arg>
                        <arg>10000</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>

<!--                        <path>-->
<!--                            <groupId>org.example</groupId>-->
<!--                            <artifactId>async-log-client</artifactId>-->
<!--                            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>-->
<!--                        </path>-->

                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

However, this causes the custom annotator to not work. Although the compilation succeeded, the custom annotation processor compilation phase was skipped straight away
If both lombok and my custom annotation processor are removed, the compilation will report an error
class org.example.async.log.client.annotation.AsyncLogProcessor (in unnamed module @0x36359723) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTrees (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.api to unnamed module @0x36359723

The git branch is here
Use the jvm parameter to open jdk.compile instead of using code
I removed module-info.java from the annotation processor.
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.13.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>21</source>
                    <target>21</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-proc:full</arg>
                        <arg>-Xlint:all</arg>
                        <arg>-verbose</arg>
                        <arg>-XprintRounds</arg>
                        <arg>-XprintProcessorInfo</arg>
                        <arg>-Xmaxerrs</arg>
                        <arg>10000</arg>

                        <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.model=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.jvm=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>

                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.example</groupId>
                            <artifactId>async-log-client</artifactId>
                            <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                        </path>

                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


The error still happened.
: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.example.async.log.client.annotation.AsyncLogProcessor (in unnamed module @0x77429040) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTrees (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.api to unnamed module @0x77429040

To this I added <fork>true<fork> referenced by here. when I remove lombok, the error still happens. whenn I don't remove lombok, my annotation processor is skiped

Are you sure the library is on the module path? Because this sounds like it is on the classpath instead. All libraries, even with a module-info.class, on the classpath, will be in the unnamed module.

Thank you for your reply. How do I set the project to module path via Maven?

Unfortunately, I don't know.

I would suggest changing the question to  "Ensure annotation processing via modulepath" (while accessing the jdk.compiler internal APIs).

In the section "Use the jvm parameter to open jdk.compile instead of using code", you seem to have not really use all the args as in the answer.

<arg>-proc:none</arg> will disable all annotation processors

The question is puzzling. Annotation processors have become bad since JDK9+

--add-opens is invalid judging by the error that occurred.

@Photon Yeah, it feels the same. Looking at lombok as a reference, seems like that itself doesn't really work around with jdk.compiler anymore. module-info.java to refer from the project. So a migration might possibly be required.

Have a look and the code again:
private void implAddExportsOrOpens(String pn,
                                       Module other,
                                       boolean open,
                                       boolean syncVM) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(other);
        Objects.requireNonNull(pn);

        // all packages are open in unnamed, open, and automatic modules
        if (!isNamed() || descriptor.isOpen() || descriptor.isAutomatic())
            return;
…

This method is invoked on the runtime representation of the module to open (jdk.compiler) and receives the module to which the package should be opened (the unnamed module in your case) as argument to the parameter other.
The check is performed on the the module to open, jdk.compiler in your case, because, as the comment says, the unnamed module would already be open. Since jdk.compiler is a named module, the check will succeed.

But you have to understand the difference between an open package and an exported package. An open package can be accessed via Reflection with access override but not by ordinary code, i.e. bytecode instructions for field accesses or method invocations.
You haven’t shown the code of AsyncLogProcessor but the error message indicates that it tries to perform a direct access that would require the package to be exported:
class org.example.async.log.client.annotation.AsyncLogProcessor (in unnamed module @0x201c3cda) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTrees (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.api to unnamed module @0x201c3cda

Note how it complains that the module “does not export” the package.
You have to do either, change the hack to add an export relationship rather then open or change the AsyncLogProcessor to use Reflection with access override instead of accessing the internal classes directly.

I do understand that the suggestion made here should help OP fix the issue faced. But, should it be considered a better practice to evolve such implementation around annotation processing with the use of java.compiler?

@Naman The API for annotation processors does not support modifying the code, not even when using the extended API of the jdk.compiler module. So any tool like Lombok is a hack. I think the OP is aware of that when accessing private methods via Unsafe. There is no clean alternative.
